# php file is returning an empty array, can't display user info

Tags: java, php, android

I am using php to connect my android app to a database hosted online. Here is the link to the page that holds the php files so you can see what it is outputting, an empty array, http://6mansquad.esy.es

The one that's giving me problems is fetchUserData which is supposed to use the username and password given by the user to search for that user and then display all of the other rows of the User table that match the username.

This is my php file that is connecting to the database (I know the connection is good because my register activity successfully creates a new row in the column).

```
<?php
/*server, user, password, databse */
$conn=mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx","xxx");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];  

$statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
if($statement === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($conn)); }

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);


mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
//printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($statement));
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $username, $name, $sex, $age, $password);
$user = array ();
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[name] = $name;
    $user[sex] = $sex;
    $user[age] = $age;
    $user[password] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

The problem I have with my app is that when I click to log in, it takes me straight back to the login screen. I have it set up so that a function is called to check if a user is logged in and if they are it displays their info, and if not it takes you back to the log in screen.

Here are the related files

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button bLogin;
EditText etUsername, etFirst, etLast, etSex, etAge, etPassword;
TextView tvRegisterLink;

UserLocalStore userLocalStore;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);
    userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bLogin:
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();


            User user = new User(username, password);

            authenticate(user);
            break;

        case R.id.tvRegisterLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
private void authenticate(User user){
    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequests.fetchUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {
            if (returnedUser == null) {
                showErrorMessage();
            } else {
                logUserIn(returnedUser);
            }
        }
    });
}
private void showErrorMessage(){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Incorrect user info");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}
private void logUserIn(User returnedUser){
    userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
    userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);

    startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
}
/*public void openHome(View view) {
    //build the intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}*/
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_games) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
public void openHome(View view) {
    // build the intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}


public class User {
String username, name, sex, password;


 int age;

    public User (String username, String name, String sex, int age,
                 String password){

        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.age = age;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = "";
        this.sex = "N/A";
        this.age = -1;
    }

}

    public class UserLocalStore {

    public static final String SP_NAME = "userDetails";
    SharedPreferences userLocalDatabase;

    public UserLocalStore(Context context) {
        userLocalDatabase = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, 0);
    }

    public void storeUserData(User user){
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
        spEditor.putString("username", user.username);
        spEditor.putString("name", user.name);
        spEditor.putString("sex", user.sex);
        spEditor.putInt("age", user.age);
        spEditor.putString("password", user.password);
    }

    public User getLoggedInUser(){
        String username = userLocalDatabase.getString("username", "");
        String name = userLocalDatabase.getString("name", "");
        String sex = userLocalDatabase.getString("sex", "");
        int age = userLocalDatabase.getInt("age", -1);
        String password = userLocalDatabase.getString("password", "");

        User storedUser = new User(username, name, sex, age, password);

        return storedUser;

    }

    public void setUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn){
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
        spEditor.putBoolean("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        spEditor.commit();
    }


    public boolean getUserLoggedIn(){
        if (userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("LoggedIn", false)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void clearUserData(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
        spEditor.clear();
        spEditor.commit();

    }


}


public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button openHome;
    Button bLogout;
    TextView etUsername, etName, etSex, etAge;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        etUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etSex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etSex);
        etAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);

        bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (authenticate() == true) {
            displayUserDetails();
        }else{
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }

    private boolean authenticate(){
        return userLocalStore.getUserLoggedIn();
    }

    private void displayUserDetails(){
        User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

        etUsername.setText(user.username);
        etName.setText(user.name);
        etSex.setText(user.sex);
        etAge.setText(user.age + "");

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bLogout:
                userLocalStore.clearUserData();
                userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);



                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }



}

public class ServerRequests {
    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://6mansquad.esy.es/";


    public ServerRequests(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storedUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();

    }

    public void fetchUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback callBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, callBack).execute();
    }

    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sex", user.sex));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(null);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }
    }


    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallback;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallback = userCallback;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser = null;

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                if (jObject.length() == 0) {
                    returnedUser = null;
                } else {

                    String name = jObject.getString("name");
                    String sex = jObject.getString("sex");
                    int age = jObject.getInt("age");


                    returnedUser = new User(user.username, name, sex, age, user.password);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            return returnedUser;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallback.done(user);
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);

        }
    }
}




public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button bLogin;
    EditText etUsername, etFirst, etLast, etSex, etAge, etPassword;
    TextView tvRegisterLink;

    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);
        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bLogin:
                String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();


                User user = new User(username, password);

                authenticate(user);
                break;

            case R.id.tvRegisterLink:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
    private void authenticate(User user){
        ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
        serverRequests.fetchUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(User returnedUser) {
                if (returnedUser == null) {
                    showErrorMessage();
                } else {
                    logUserIn(returnedUser);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void showErrorMessage(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Incorrect user info");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        dialogBuilder.show();
    }
    private void logUserIn(User returnedUser){
        userLocalStore.storeUserData(returnedUser);
        userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
    }
    /*public void openHome(View view) {
        //build the intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_games) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    public void openHome(View view) {
        // build the intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

ServerRequests is connecting to the database and calling the php file (fetchUserdata). The login activity is the one that is supposed to check if the user is logged in and then go to the profile activity to display the info, but when I click login it's just going back to the login activity page.

Comment: **Please, *do not*** store *clear-text* passwords.

Comment: It's strictly for a class project my professor told us to only worry about security once we have it finished.